# Passing Field Symbol value to Return parameter of method

Tags: methods, abap

I have the below code which uses a method. When I try to assign the Field Symbol value `[Type ANY]` to the return parameter `RO_TAB [Type Ref to Data]`, I am getting an error message `OBJECTS_MOVE_NOT SUPPORTED [Conversion of type "l" to type "g" not supported.]`.

The issue is happening after a BW system upgrade along with which we also moved to ABAP objects. The code executes perfectly in the older version of ABAP.

The dump occurs in the below line:

```
RO_TAB = <lf_storage>.
```

I have no idea why.

```
method GET_LU_STORAGE_FOR_ODS.
* IMPORTS
*  IF_ODS TYPE RSODSTECH
*  IF_ODS_TABLE_TYPE TYPE ZODS_TAB_TYPE
* RETURNS
*  RO_TAB TYPE REF TO DATA

  FIELD-SYMBOLS:
    <lf_storage> TYPE ANY.

  DATA:
    lf_index       TYPE SY-TABIX,
    lf_sindex      TYPE STRING,
    lf_name        TYPE STRING.


  lf_index = GET_LU_STORAGE_INDEX(
    IF_ODS = IF_ODS
    IF_ODS_TABLE_TYPE = IF_ODS_TABLE_TYPE ).

  lf_sindex = lf_index.
  CONCATENATE
    'MO_LU_DATA_'
    lf_sindex
    INTO lf_name.

  ASSIGN lf_name TO <lf_storage>.
  RO_TAB = <lf_storage>.

endmethod.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a data object first, using the `CREATE DATA` statement. Then you can `ASSIGN` a field symbol to work with the dynamically created data object. There's an example in the online manual. A field symbol is not a reference, it simply places the variable assigned to it in its position. You're effectively trying to  move a string (which is what `lf_name` is) to a reference variable, and that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a variable of type `STRING` to a variable of type `REF TO DATA`.

The following code snippet shows how it should be done.

```
DATA: lf_name TYPE string.
DATA: lo_tab TYPE REF TO DATA.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lf_name> TYPE string.

lf_name = 'test'.
GET REFERENCE OF lf_name INTO lo_tab.
*lf_name = lo_tab. "this is not allowed
ASSIGN lo_tab->* TO <lf_name>.
```

So in your case it would be sufficient to define a field symbol.

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lf_name> TYPE STRING.
```

then assign the contents referenced by `RO_TAB` to this field symbol.

```
ASSIGN ro_tab->* TO <lf_name>.
```

and finally do the concatenation.

```
CONCATENATE
  'MO_LU_DATA_'
  lf_index
  INTO <lf_name>.
```

That's all! No further assignments should be required.

Answer (score -1):

How about just this?

```
  lf_sindex = lf_index.
  CONCATENATE
    'MO_LU_DATA_'
    lf_sindex
    INTO RO_TAB.
```

Comment: This does not work, because of the the same fact, that the code in question does not.

Comment: You are right. I guess what I tried(and failed) to convey was that this method should return data( not a reference to data).